# Downloading ear file from nexus using maven dependency plugin get goal

Tags: maven, nexus, ear

I am using the maven dependency plugin [get](http://maven.apache.org/plugins-archives/maven-dependency-plugin-2.5.1/get-mojo.html) goal to download an artefact from nexus. I can use it to download jar as per below

`mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:get -DrepoUrl=http://nexus.url/nexus/content/groups/public-all/ -Dartifact=groupId:artifactId:version:jar -Dtransitive=false -Ddestination=/my/path`

To download a war I can use

`mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:get -DrepoUrl=http://nexus.url/nexus/content/groups/public-all/ -Dartifact=groupId:artifactId:version:war -Dtransitive=false -Ddestination=/my/path`

I am however failing to download an ear using the following

`mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:get -DrepoUrl=http://nexus.url/nexus/content/groups/public-all/ -Dartifact=groupId:artifactId:version:ear -Dtransitive=false -Ddestination=/my/path`

The output of the above command is as per below

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:get (default-cli) @ standalone-pom ---
[INFO] Resolving groupId:artifactId:ear:version
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.797 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-10-20T13:31:02+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/19M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have confirmed that the ear is indeed present in Nexus. The above command runs successfully but the ear is not actually downloaded. 
What is wrong with the above command to download the ear? How can I download an ear file from Nexus using the mvn command?

Do note that I have replaced the actual groupId, artifactId and versions in the code above with their respective words.

Comment: What is the command line output of the last goal?

Comment: I have updated the question with the output of the command